# PHPUnit tearDownAfterClass() does not seem to work properly

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I have the following code:

```
class ProfileTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    protected static $nLastProfileId;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        self::$nLastProfileId = 0;
    }

    public function testCreateProfile()
    {
        self::$nLastProfileId = profile_create("TestProfileCreation123");
        $this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual(1, self::$nLastProfileId);
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException PDOException
     */
    public function testThatThereCanNotBeTwoProfilesWithTheSameName()
    {
        profile_create("TestProfileCreation123");
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {
        profile_delete(self::$nLastProfileId);
    }

}
```

`profile_create` adds a profile to a database and `profile_delete` deletes that profile from the database based on its ID. Two profiles can not have the same name.

The problem I have is that if `testThatThereCanNotBeTwoProfilesWithTheSameName()` is commented the test unit works properly. It creates a new entry  in the database and at the end it deletes it. Once I uncomment that function, the test unit fails on the second run because it does not delete the entry in the database.

Do you have any idea why that happens?